# Is it possible to access a specific pallet's storage item in the function `<Runtime as TaggedTransactionQueue<Block>::validate_transaction()`?

Tags: runtime, storage, validation

I want to access a specific pallet's storage item (for example: a `StorageMap` or `StorageValue`) in the function `<Runtime as TaggedTransactionQueue<Block>::validate_transaction()` (note: this function is found in runtime/src/lib.rs FYI).

Therefore, I am wondering, is it possible to access the value of a pallet's storage item outside of the pallet and in runtime/src/lib.rs (specifically in `<Runtime as TaggedTransactionQueue<Block>::validate_transaction()`) itself? Thanks

@shawn-tabrizi :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. `validate_transaction` will be called in the context of some block and in this context you can read the pallet storage items.

While you can read storage items, you also need to ensure that you are staying in certain limits. For example you should not do any kind of storage iteration. The problem with all this is that every node will call `validate_transaction` before adding a transaction to the tx-pool and also when the transaction is in the pool to check if it is still valid. All these operations are "free" and make it possible to dos your node. So, ensure that you are not doing too many storage reads or doing too many calculations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Btw do you know what the function is for reading a specific pallet storage item from the `block_hash` parameter?

Comment: I don't get your question, sorry. What you mean by "storage item from the `block_hash` parameter"?

Comment: Let's say palletX has the storage item: `let DummyStorageNumber = StorageValue<_, u64, ValueQuery>`. How do I access the value of `DummyStorageNumber`  in `<Runtime as TaggedTransactionQueue<Block>>::validate_transaction(source, tx, block_hash)`? Thanks

Comment: `palletx::DummyStorageNumber::get()`

Comment: I see. Thanks, it works :). Btw could I ask when it is appropriate to use `<Runtime as TaggedTransactionQueue<Block>::validate_transaction()` and when it is appropriate to use `frame_system::Config::BaseCallFilter` to filter/validate transactions? Thanks again!

Comment: @SubstrateUser could you maybe create a separate question for this and give more context? I can not really follow on what you mean. Could you also tag my answer as solution if you are happy with it?

Comment: Sure. Here is the separate question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6239/runtime-as-taggedtransactionqueueblockvalidate-transaction-vs-frame-s. Thanks again :)

Comment: Please also accept this as answer here :P