# `<Runtime as TaggedTransactionQueue<Block>>::validate_transaction()` vs `frame_system::Config::BaseCallFilter` for checking for a valid transaction

Tags: runtime, transactions, validation

When is it appropriate to use `<Runtime as TaggedTransactionQueue<Block>>::validate_transaction()` to check if a transaction is valid (and reject a transaction if it is invalid) and when is it appropriate to use `frame_system::Config::BaseCallFilter` to check if a transaction is valid (and reject a transaction if it is invalid)?

It seems as though they both do almost the same thing? Except that `validate_transaction()` returns `ValidateTransaction` (https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/transaction_validity/type.TransactionValidity.html) while `<BaseCallFilter as Contains::<RuntimeCall>>::contains()` returns a boolean.

Thank you :)

@shawn-tabrizi :)

@bkchr :)

Answer (score 1):

Both are serving different purposes:

1. `validate_transaction`: This is being used by the transaction pool to validate transactions. This means checking that stuff like the nonce is correct and that the user has funds to pay for the fees. This api is also not required to be called by the node, the node could also just skip calling this.
2. `BaseCallFilter`: This is being used when applying a transaction. It will filter all calls that are being dispatched and if they are not allowed the dispatch will fail. This is for example useful to prevent executing certain calls in your runtime.

Both are being used in different parts of your chain and also serve quite different purposes. As the node is not required to call `validate_transaction`, your runtime logic also needs to ensure that there is never a transaction being applied that violates certain assumptions. An assumption could for example be that the chain doesn't allow balance transfers in the early stage of the network. So, `validate_transaction` being an utility function the node side to get certain information about a transaction, but not being a tool for you to ensure that only valid state transitions are happening.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mentioned that the runtime-api `validate_transaction()` is "not required to be called by the node, the node could also just skip calling this." But I assume that a block-authoring node has to check `validate_transaction()` before it authors a block, correct?

Comment: Every node that follows the normal protocol will always call `validate_transaction` before a transaction enters the pool. A block producer will not call this function before pushing transactions to the block. As I already tried to explain above, the runtime needs to ensure that transactions that are being applied are valid. This means it will basically run the same checks as in `validate_transaction`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. **When you say "the runtime needs to ensure that _transactions that are being applied are valid_" - is this supposed to be done in `<Runtime as sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder<Block>>::apply_extrinsic()`?** (because I notice that in the node-template - it calls `Executive::apply_extrinsic(extrinsic)` (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L371-L373) - which calls the `SignedExtension::pre_dispatch()` function of all the signed extensions (i.e  of `CheckNonce`, `CheckWeight` etc.)

Comment: Yes exactly. You can use `SignedExtension`s to extend these checks in your runtime.

Comment: So then I am confused. What is the difference between `<Runtime as sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder<Block>>::apply_extrinsic()` and `<BaseCallFilter as Contains::<RuntimeCall>>::contains()`? Don't they both "ensure that transactions that are being applied are valid"? Thanks

Comment: `BaseCallFilter` works on the "call level", while `apply_extrinsic` works on the "extrinsic/transaction level". One extrinsic can consist of multiple nested calls. A call is also not signed, the entire extrinsic is signed. You also don't have a nonce per call, you have one nonce per extrinsic. Etc. Basically these are just quite different concepts and levels. Both may share similar characteristics, but they are not the same. Like you may want to prevent that an inner proxy call changes the proxy setup. This extrinsic being valid, while the executed calls are trying forbidden operations.